# Photoshop CS5 - Brush - Alt key - Eyedropper tool - how to return back

Tags: flash-cs5, photoshop, alt

First I'm not some kind of exper for photoshop! I like to put in my picture another picture to be like Lyer, then I go to Layer - Layer Mask - Reveal all... to wipe things I don't want with brush... But I click Alt key and Eyedropper tool appeared with circle and no it not working and I clicked... I don't know how to bring it back... Foreground color and Background color I don't understend that if that is the problem..

Comment: Please, check what's on-topic and what's not on each site before asking ([help/on-topic]). See the full list of Stack sites: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the white and black mask rectangle on that layer. It will have a link right in front of the rectangle. That rectangle gives you a preview of what you have revealed in white and whats not in black. Looks like a thumbnail of your mask. That will bring it back